# Inheritance sec rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'

Tags: asp.net, owin, typeloadexception

I am Trying to access Active Directory data through graph API. i am getting the following error on running the application.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**  "System.TypeLoadException: **Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible**."

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.]
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware.ResolveHttpMessageHandler(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options) +0
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware..ctor(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options) +996
   lambda_method(Closure , OwinMiddleware , IAppBuilder , OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions ) +54

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +92
   System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args) +117
   System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args) +12
   Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.BuildInternal(Type signature) +236
   Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.Build(Type returnType) +21
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup) +565
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +95
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +72
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +96
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +523
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +364
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +770
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +195


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1
```

As i am a beginner i am struck with the error. Could any one please let me know what needs to be done to overcome this error

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: The issue has been resolved in System.Net.Http version 4.3.1 after 22 Feb 2017

Answer (score 38):

It seems the bug has now been closed on GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11100) and a new version of `System.Net.Http` has been released.

I was able to upgrade `System.Net.Http` to version `4.3.1` with NuGet and that solved the issue.

Comment: @RobVonNesselrode, note that ver 4.3.1 was available only after 22Feb 2017

Comment: I agree with @Rob Von Nesselrode
This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me:
System.Net.Http v4.1.0.0 seems to have some issues. In web.config or app.config, point to the old version (v4.0.0.0)

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     ...
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Note, that when you install a new unrelated NuGet package, the bindingRedirect changes may be overwritten, and you need to set binding to 4.0.0.0 again.

Answer (score 6):

I found upgrading `System.Net.Http` via `Nuget` fixes it.

Comment: Same here, project is .Net 4.6.1, got the error, Nuget updated System.Net.Http from 4.3.0 to 4.3.4, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I solved with downgrade `System.Net.Http` from `4.3.0` to `4.0.0` with Visual Studio `NuGet Package Manager`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the problem working with .net core web application (.net framework). I have tried everything I've read hear, but only migrating to .net 4.5.1 from .net 4.6.1 helped.